# Connect Apache OFBIZ database to website application (HTML,CSS,JS)

Tags: database, apache, web-services, ofbiz

Im trying to connect a website i've built using HTML, CSS and JS to the Apache OFBIZ database I have built.

The web app's main purpose is to allow the user to download the app and order the case, and allow them to put in their personal details including method of payment and purchase the case through, by connecting to the OFBIZ data base which has a number of fields that once approved will confirm the order and notify the relevant members of the manufacturing process and allow the user to see that their order has been received and confirmed.

thanks in advance,

H

Comment: what is the issue you face when trying to connect?

Comment: there is no issue, im trying to work out how to connect a my website application to the apache ofbiz. As i am relatively new to using ofbiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OFBiz is a web development framework with ERP business modules on top of it. It's made to be enhanced and you can build your own web applications with OFBiz. I would simply build the website with OFBiz, providing a form for the user detail input. You will have all options to use the database, services etc..

If you have to access OFBiz with a native app (IOS, Android & Co.) you might want to implement some RESTful services to connect OFBiz with your app.

From what I understand, I would migrate the website to OFBiz. If it has a responsive UI design, it will run nicely on smartphones.

Comment: HI Michael, Thanks for the tip! am I able to simply copy paste my code from my HTML, CSS,  JS files into Apache ofbiz? is that what you mean by migrating the website?

Comment: It is not as simple as copy & paste. You will have to put your code in template files, define screens and controller targets to have everything together. You will have to learn some OFBiz basic mechanisms.
The good things is, there are plenty of examples you can learn from in the existing applications.

Comment: Great! ill get straight to learning the OFbiz mechanics! Thanks Michael!